# Q_OBJECT and moc for inheritance

Tags: c++, qt

I am working in a project where a Q_OBJECT macro is used in a class which I need to inherit.

The class where Q_OBJECT is already defined  looks like this,

```
class cBaseObject : public QObject, public cinformation
{
    Q_OBJECT
    //...
    //...
}
```

I am creating a new class via public inheritance of cBaseObject. Should I need to write Q_OBJECT macro again?
I tried with and without that macro and I am seeing no moc_XXX.cxx file is generated if I didn't include the QT_MACRO

```
class cEnhancedbaseObject : public cBaseObject
{
    Q_OBJECT   // if i didn't include this 
          //no moc__XXX.cxx file is  generated
}
```

But when I inherit the class why the Q_OBJECT macro's functionality is also not inherited. 
Is it any problem if Q_OBJECT macro is defined twice, if it is inherited? How does the behavior of Q_OBJECT for multilevel inheritance. I have read that for multiple inheritance the QOBJECT class should be placed first. Is there anything similar for multilevel inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The presence of the `Q_OBJECT` macro marks the class for inclusion in Qt's meta-object system. If you want your class to have its own identity in this meta-object system, you must put the `Q_OBJECT` macro into it (and make sure it is directly or indirectly derived from `QObject`, naturally).

In your case of `cBaseObject` and `cEnhancedbaseObject`, if `cEnhancedbaseObject` does not include the `Q_OBJECT` macro, it will still work normally. However, as far Qt's meta-object system is concerned, objects of type `cEnhancedbaseObject` will be of meta-type `cBaseObject`. You can see that using such functions as `myObject->metaObject()->className()`.

Comment: It’s worth noting that slots and signals can be declared without Q_OBJECT, but connecting them will fail at runtime only (when using the old-style/dynamic connects), which is a nasty pitfall. In general, each QObject subclass should have the Q_OBJECT macro by default, unless one really knows what he’s doing. The only good reason for not having the macro I could think of are templated subclasses of a QObject-derived base classes.